# Android firebase authentication error in .java file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate login and signup with Firebase. I was following this article on [android hive](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/) 
but there was lot of errors, one was this,

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

for complete detail version of the code you can follow the above "android hive" link.

Comment: You need to provide a snippet of your code so that people can help you. Please edit your question. Also please be sure to put code and log entries in the appropriate formatting blocks (see the buttons at the top of the editor when you are typing your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Firebase Assistant for adding Firebase Authenitcation.

To open the Firebase Assistant in Android Studio:

1. Click Tools > Firebase to open the Assistant window.
2. Click to expand one of the listed features (for example,
   Authentication), Click the Connect to Firebase button to connect to
   Firebase Project.
3. Select your project from Firebase console.

It'll automatically add the correct dependencies for your project.